# Erlang parallel server using sockets

Tags: socket, server, erlang

The task was to build a simple parallel server in erlang that prints what it receives through a socket and alerts when the socket is closed.

```
-module(server).
-export([start/0]).


start() ->
    {ok, ListenSocket} = gen_tcp:listen(8211,[binary,{packet,4},{active, once}]),
    spawn(fun() -> accepter(ListenSocket) end),
  sleep().


sleep() ->
    receive
        cancel -> void
    end.

accepter(ListenSocket) -> 
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket),
    spawn(fun() -> accepter(ListenSocket) end),
    Proc = spawn(fun() -> worker(Socket) end),
    gen_tcp:controlling_process(Socket, Proc).



worker(Socket) -> 

    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Data} -> 
            io:format("Received ~p",[Data]),
            inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
            worker(Socket);
        {tcp_closed, Socket} -> 
            io:format("Socket ~p closed",[Socket])
    end.
```

Is this the correct way of building such a thing?

Comment: Is your incoming data formed into packets, preceded with four length-bytes? I guess no. [There](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#setopts-2) is more about {packet, PacketType} option

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your solution function by function. First, `start/0`:

```
start() ->
    {ok, ListenSocket} = gen_tcp:listen(8211,[binary,{packet,4},{active, once}]),
    spawn(fun() -> accepter(ListenSocket) end),
    sleep().
```

First, port 8211 is hard-coded. You might instead want to export both a `start/0` and a `start/1`, the latter taking a port number argument, with `start/0` calling `start/1` with 8211 as the default. You don't need `{packet,4}` unless your Erlang client is also using that option, or your non-Erlang client precedes each packet with a 4-byte integer in network order that indicates the packet length. You probably also want to use the `{reuseaddr,true}` option so that you can stop the application and quickly start it again on the same port. With all these changes, we wind up with this:

```
start() ->
    start(8211).
start(Port) ->
    {ok, ListenSocket} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, [binary,{active,once},{reuseaddr,true}]),
    spawn(fun() -> acceptor(ListenSocket) end),
    sleep().
```

(Note that technically you don't need the `sleep/0` call, but I'm sure you put it there to make the program easier to work with interactively from an Erlang shell, so I'm leaving it.)

Next, we have `sleep/0`:

```
sleep() ->
    receive
        cancel -> void
    end.
```

I would return `ok` here, since that's extremely common in Erlang. Using the atom `void` is not.

Next, we have `acceptor/1`:

```
acceptor(ListenSocket) -> 
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket),
    spawn(fun() -> acceptor(ListenSocket) end),
    Proc = spawn(fun() -> worker(Socket) end),
    gen_tcp:controlling_process(Socket, Proc).
```

The big problem here is the spawning of the worker process, and then handing control of the accepted socket over to it. There are two problems with this:

1. The accepted socket inherits `{active,once}` from the listen socket. But what happens if a message arrives after the worker is spawned but before control of the socket is given to it? The message is queued to the controlling process, which is *the acceptor process*, not the new worker process. The worker process misses that message, and since the acceptor never checks it, the message just gets lost.
2. Once the acceptor accepts a connection, it spawns a new acceptor. This is good. But it then spawns a worker, gives it the control of the socket, and then dies. This is pointless. Since the acceptor spawns a new acceptor, it can just continue and call `worker/1` itself, and that way it can avoid the problem of changing the socket's controlling process, which means it won't miss any messages.

We can fix these problems by revising `acceptor/1` like this:

```
acceptor(ListenSocket) -> 
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket),
    spawn(fun() -> acceptor(ListenSocket) end),
    worker(Socket).
```

And finally, we have the original `worker/1` function:

```
worker(Socket) ->
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Data} -> 
            io:format("Received ~p", [Data]),
            inet:setopts(Socket, [{active,once}]),
            worker(Socket);
        {tcp_closed, Socket} -> 
            io:format("Socket ~p closed", [Socket])
    end.
```

This function looks just right, no changes needed.